# CSS Image color overlay on kisscut image png

Tags: html, css, css-filters

Hi I am trying to color overlay an image that is kiss cut transparent png, sort of like photoshop color overlay with opacity control.

I have tried searching but can't find this particular solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/j2e83gxq/9/

```css
.imgoverlay {
  width:500px;
  padding-top:500px;
  background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Android_robot.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-color:cyan;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgoverlay">
</div>
```

All I could find was using background-color but this colors the whole Element, I just need it to overlay a image only and not the transparent side its on.

So basically i am trying to color overlay this image:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Android_robot.png

with different color.

Comment: where is the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have added code that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this effect in CSS, the best way to do this will be using Photoshop.